# Rails app deployed at amazon aws and not all migration files get migrated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm deploying my rails app at amazon aws and all works well, but after a while I have noticed that not all the migration files are being migrated and also some columns are missing from some tables. When I check inside the folder of the current app uploaded via ssh some migration files are missing. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

This the `database.yml` file setup:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Comment: Sounds like the files are not being copied to the aws instance properly.  How are you deploying the application?  That's where the issue lies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dbugger, I'm deploying the app with `eb deploy name_of_environment` via the terminal.

Comment: Are the only files missing the migration files?  Have you deployed every commit or are using an .ebignore file?

Comment: The only files that are missing are few migrations files. First I `git commit` all the changes and then `eb deploy name_of_environment`. That's the process I follow to deploy the app.

Comment: Sounds like you missed a commit -- I'd just manually copy the files and run a migration.